# Why can I not do a Messagebox.Show(some_int)?

Tags: c#, .net

```
MessageBox.Show((some_string.Length).ToString);
```

I am getting two errors for this:

1. The best overloaded method match for 'System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(string)'
2. Argument '1': cannot convert from 'method group' to 'string'

Can someone tell me how to do this correctly?

Comment: If you don't include the **()** on the end of ToString(), the compiler thinks you're trying to pass the ToString method itself, rather than its return value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Functions need brackets when they are called, you are missing `()` at the end of `ToString`

```
MessageBox.Show((some_string.Length).ToString());
```

The errors:

*Error 1 The best overloaded method match for 'System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(string)'*

This is just saying that it is expecting a string (`MessageBox.Show()`), and you did not provide it with one.

*Error 2 Argument '1': cannot convert from 'method group' to 'string'*

This is saying that you cannot convert a method group (`ToString` without brackets to make it a function call) as a string parameter in the required method.

Answer (score 5):

```
MessageBox.Show((some_string.Length).ToString());
```

Comment: You need the brackets for the ToString function

Answer (score 1):

```
MessageBox.Show((some_string.Length()).ToString());
```

Answer (score 1):

in you example you have forgotten the parenthesis:

```
MessageBox.Show((some_string.Length).ToString());
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to know that, `ToString` is not a property, but a method.

So you must use a pair of parenthesis.

```
MessageBox.Show((some_string.Length).ToString());
```